# Android service is frequently stopped and restarted

Tags: android, android-service, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to develop an Android application which draws a floating overlay on the screen, as it is done by Facebook messenger with chat heads.

I've created an Android service from which I handle the UI. Everything works well, but on some devices the service is stopped very frequently and sometimes it is started again after more than 60 seconds.

I know this is a behavior defined by the Android System, but I was wondering if there is a way to give my service the maximum priority. Is this possible? Could this behavior be worsened by something in my implementation which is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make your Service a "Foreground Service" as briefly explained [in Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). This means that it shows an icon and possibly some status data in the status bar. Quoting:

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory. A foreground service must provide a
>   notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing"
>   heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless
>   the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

In practice you just need to modify the Service's `onStartCommand()` method to set up the notification and to call `startForeGround()`. This example is from the Android documentation:

```java
// Set the icon and the initial text to be shown.
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text), System.currentTimeMillis());
// The pending intent is triggered when the notification is tapped.
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
// 2nd parameter is the title, 3rd one is a status message.
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title), getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
// You can put anything non-zero in place of ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID.
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

That's actually a deprecated way of setting up a notification but the idea is the same anyway even if you use `Notification.Builder`.